# Regex to match any string between quotes

Tags: regex

I have the following expression:

```
Category = context.Categories.First(x => x.Name == "API")
```

I need to match all lines with this format but instead of API it can be anything, e.g., between "" it can have anything.

I tried (https://regex101.com/r/PUuxjZ/1):

```
(?<=Category = context.Categories.First(x => x.Name == ")(.*)(?="))
```

Somehow this does not match the previous string. What am I missing?

Comment: In what language / environment?

Comment: This is to use in a  Find / Replace in Visual Studio Code. I suppose it uses C#? Not sure ...

Comment: What do you mean "it can be anything"? Are you trying to check if Category.Name has a value?

Comment: `\QCategory = context.Categories.First(x => x.Name == \E".*?"\)` Also I think you'd like to check this [*Reference - What does this regex mean?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: @MatthewMeppiel No, I just have around 3000 code lines which include that text and in each the "..." part is different. I need to replace all them by something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use lookahead and lookbehind. Just search.

```
(Category = context.Categories.First\(x => x.Name == ").*("\))
```

If you want to replace, simplify the process by replacing with the content you already matched.

```
$1SomeOtherString$2
```

Perhaps not complicated, but it works.